# Python-ldap and SSL

Tags: openssl, python-ldap

I try connect to ldap using python-ldap and ssl (linux gentoo). Server-side certificate. The server does not require a certificate from the client. I can get certificates using

```
openssl c_client -showcerts -connect ip:port
```

It display a lot of informations that contains Enterprise CA, ROOT CA and code: 20 - unable to get local issuer certificate. How to use this to connect? I must add this to ssl trusted keys? Or maybe add to ldap options while connect?

Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Glad to see you tested with openssl first ! It looks like openssl does not have the trust ca. It does not matter, but python-ldap could complain. Have you tried to establish a LDAPS connection with python-ldap ? What does it give you ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but solved it with [these instructions](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/verify-ssl-certificate-openssl/)

Basically the magic is to create a directory, put the ca certificate in that directory and run

```
 c_rehash <directoryname>
```

and run the `s_client` with parameter `-CApath <directoryname>`

On `python-ldap` you do the same by doing

```
ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_CACERTFILE, '/path/to/ca.crt')
```